# Refine the finite open covering to compact included covering

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let K be compact set in $\Bbb{R}^n$,assume $U_1,U_2,...,U_n$ be the open covering for it.Prove there eixst refinement $V_i\subset \overline{V_i}\subset U_i$ such that $\overline{V_i}$ is compact and $V_1,V_2,...,V_n$ open covers $K$ also.

My attempt due to locally compact we can find $V$ such that $K\subset V\subset \overline{V}\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ now we take $V_i = V\bigcap U_i$ comes the problem since $\overline{V_i}$ may not lies $U_i$ although it's compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in K$ then $x\in U_i$ for some $i$. Now find an open ball $B_r(x)$ ($r$ depends on $x$) such that $\overline{B_r(x)}\subset U_i$. The family of balls $\{ B_r(x)\}_{x\in K}$ covers $K$ and thus has a finite subcover

$$ K \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^N B_{r_j} (x_j).$$

For each $j$, let $i = i(j)$ so that $\overline{B_{r_j} (x_j)} \subset U_i$ (such an $i$ exists since this is how we choose the balls in the first place). Let

$$V_i = \bigcup_{j:\  i(j)=i} B_{r_j} (x_j).$$

Then $\overline{V_i} \subset U_i$, $\overline{V_i}$ is compact and $\{ V_i\}$ covers $K$.